# Maven. Копирование определённых зависимостей в JAR

Tags: java, maven, компиляция, jar, зависимости

Я уже устал самостоятельно закидывать определённые зависимости в JAR. В интернете вычитал, что оно должно само туда закидывать зависимость, но этого не происходит.
Указывал для зависимости  `<score>compile</score>`
В интернете нечего не нашёл.
Расскажите как сделать, что бы определённые зависимости закидовались автоматом в JAR файл

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven в стандартной конфигурации не собирает зависимости в JAR, для этого необходимо поставить `maven-shade-plugin`.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

* Для добавления зависимости в файл необязательно указывать `<score>compile</score>`, он соберётся автоматически. Если же хочется, чтобы зависимость не была добавлена - укажите `<score>provided</score>`.

** Если не хотите самостоятельно вызывать задачу `shade` у плагина `maven-shade-plugin` - добавьте в блок `plugin` дополнительный код:

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
             <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

*Не забывайте отмечать правильный ответ решением, нажимая на галочку, это так же помогает отвечающим :3*

Comment: Нечего не изменилось. pom.xml https://pastebin.com/7EW6r3VL Должно кидать в jar файл JDA, но не кидает

Comment: @СергейРыжков, доработанная версия pom.xml: https://pastebin.com/bUGSH1bK и версия plugin.yml с плейсхолдерами названия и версии: https://pastebin.com/PX07nv5v

Comment: @СергейРыжков, не забудьте отметить ответ решением, это так же помогает отвечающим :)